# How do I set Python None to db3 Null

Tags: python, sqlite

I have the following values In Python values:

```
_sfwBIPMKEeCTfuMZpaDEBQ Atomic Warehouse Model None
```

These values are sent through a function and is being put into a db3 table like this:

```
INSERT INTO [PackageRoster] (PkgID, Package, PkgParentID) VALUES ('_sfwBIPMKEeCTfuMZpaDEBQ', 'Atomic Warehouse Model', 'None');
```

I do not want the string 'None' put into the table.  I would like NULL.
How do I tell Python to inject NULL instead of None?

Here's the function that works the statement (includes debug feature):

```
def StorePackage(PkgID, Package, PkgParentID):
    dbutils.ResetTable()
    conn = sqlite3.connect(dbutils.db)
    try:
        conn.execute("INSERT INTO " + dbutils.table + " (PkgID, Package, PkgParentID) VALUES ('" + PkgID + "', '" + Package + "', '" + PkgParentID + "');")
    except:
        print("INSERT INTO " + dbutils.table + " (PkgID, Package, PkgParentID) VALUES ('" + PkgID + "', '" + Package + "', '" + str(PkgParentID) + "');")
    conn.commit()
```

Thanks

Comment: Use just `None` without quotes.

Comment: since it's going through a function, it converts None to 'None'.  how do I revert?  Thanks

Comment: Where are you calling this function `StorePackage` and what is the actual data you are passing?

Comment: sorry.  they were values, not variables.  Each stored in it's own variable.  I re-edited the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I initially commented a recommendation to use parameter substitution, assuming it wasn't actually related. On further inspection, though, I think it's exactly what you're looking for.

Your code currently inserts all strings because you're explicitly converting everything to a string in Python. Parameter substitution enables Python to handle how to get its values into the database, and also protects you from SQL injection attacks.

```
conn.execute("INSERT INTO " + dbutils.table + " (PkgID, Package, PkgParentID) VALUES (?,?,?)", (PkgID, Package, PkgParentID))
```

A Python `None` object will be inserted as an SQLite `NULL` using this method. You can read more about parameter substitution in [the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html), as well as how Python values are converted to SQLite values and vice versa.

Comment: Well "if" he would have used parameter substitution, he would have avoided this issue. But its not parameter substitution which causes his issue. I do agree that using parameter substition should be encouraged though

Answer (score 1):

You are converting all of your values to strings, because you add quotes arround them. I.e, because you do `'" + str(PkgParentID) + "'` it will end up as `'None'` instead of `None`.

You should for example convert your values to a string before the query, and replace them with `NULL` when they are None:

```
def StorePackage(PkgID, Package, PkgParentID):
    PkgParentID = "'{}'".format(PkgParentID) if PkgParentID is not None else "NULL"
    # Same for other parameters if desired

    dbutils.ResetTable()
    conn = sqlite3.connect(dbutils.db)
    query = "INSERT INTO " + dbutils.table + " (PkgID, Package, PkgParentID) VALUES ('" + PkgID + "', '" + Package + "', " + PkgParentID + ");"
    try:
        conn.execute(query)
    except:
        print(query)
    conn.commit()
```

Also you should use [parameter substitution,](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html) although thats not what is causing your issue in the first place

Comment: Seems he deleted this comment. Let me add the link

Comment: Ok.  I wish I could give two check marks.  Thanks much.